# What is Commutation Enhancement in BLHeli_M and what should i set it to?

Tags: esc, blheli

In the BLHeli_M version of the BLHeli Configurator, theres an Option for Commutation Enhancement. By default its set to Async-PWM but it can be set from 3%-CE to 100%-CE. What does this Parameter do and what should i set it to on a Mobula 6?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BLHeli_M Commutation Enhancement feature is intended to increase motor power response times by "overdriving" (*my words, may not be the most appropriate analogy*) the coils to charge/discharge them more quickly.

---

Source: ([rgroups.om](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=44749435&postcount=24))

> Commutation is a job to charge two of three coils, A B and C, sequentially.
> Enhancement is an attempt to make the charge time shorter.
> Sync-PWM try to apply power at the very right moment without delay.
> Enhancement try to make the charge speed faster.

Source: ([rcgroups.com](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3621257-BLHeli_M-Maverick-version))

> Commutation Enhancement(CE)
> Use more power when charging the coils to speed up settling time of motor current. RPM will be higher with the same throttle.
> Many request for normal RPM after disarm. So CE will be off right after startup. Then is on after a certain dshot transistion detected. After that, CE will be off after arming(dshot=0).

---

As for advice on whether or not to enable it on your Mobula 6, I'm not quite sure. From reading the development descriptions written by JazzMaverick (*the primary maintainer of BLHeli_M*), it appears that the feature was built to "accelerate" motors/ESCs in the 5" class, although I do see a couple mentions of applications for whoop-sized drones in the RCGroups thread.

I'd try leaving the defaults as-is and then coming back to investigate your options for changing the commutation enhancement setting later on if you feel like the quad's motor performance is lacking. Granted, I've never used the feature before, so take my recommendation here with a grain of salt. :)